# Can i use AVAudioRecorder for sending a stream of recordings to server?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to write a program for live streaming the audio to the server. Does AVAudioRecorder has the streaming functionality or should I use any other frameworks? Preferably I am trying to use apple builtin frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used AVCaptureSession for streaming audio coupled with AVCaptureDevice as Audio as input device and output device as AVCaptureAudioDataOutput which in turn calls AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate and gives data as a buffered stream.

[AVFoundation Cameras and Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder), you have to initialize an AVAudioRecorder with a file path, which means: if you want to do the live streaming, you have to either wait for the current recording to finish, or initialize a new AVAudioRecorder with another path.

I would recommend you to create multiple AVAudioRecorder instances and run each instance based on the size of the audio chunk. (You can also divide them based on the time, but make sure your buffer is large to keep them all)

And, just upload previous chunks and then start a new instance to keep the recording going on.